# Unicode data over socket in C# client & C++ server

Tags: c#, c++, string, sockets, unicode

I have a C# client and a C++ server. I am sending a user's facebook name via sockets. I write the length of the name at the beginning. For example: 
`05/*sizeofname*/ getbytes("asdfg")`
 I dont get an error. But if I try to do this:
`05/*size of name*/ getbytes("İasdf")`, it reads only `İasd`
because `İ` has two bytes. But other letters have 1 byte. I dont know how to read it correctly in the C++ server.

Server C++:

```
byte firstlen = packet.byteread();
                if (firstlen >= 150 || firstlen <= 0) { printf("first %d came\n", firstlen); goto hataver; }
                char * firstname = new char[firstlen];
                firstname = (char*)packet.charread(firstlen);
                printf("income firstname = %s\n", firstname);

char * charread(int idlen)
{
    char * retarray = new char[idlen];
    memcpy(retarray, buffs + marker, idlen);
    marker += idlen;
    retarray[idlen] = 0;
    return retarray;
}
```

Client C#

```
yenisi.eklestrlen(firstname, (byte)sizeof(profile.FirstName)); //(byte)firstname.Length);

    public void eklestrlen(string eklenecek,byte uzunluk)
    {
        ekle1(uzunluk);
        ekles(eklenecek);
    }

    public void ekle1(byte eklenecek)
    {
        Paket2[marker] = eklenecek;
        marker++;// eklenecek.Length;
    }

    public void ekles(string eklenecek2)
    {
        byte[] eklenecek = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(eklenecek2);
        Array.Copy(eklenecek, 0, Paket2, marker, eklenecek.Length);
        marker += eklenecek.Length;

    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide (post) a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

If "İ" has two bytes and the others have one, you're most likely encoding the string value using UTF8 encoding.

You don't share enough of your C++/C# code to know what's exactly going on. On the C side, you should be able to use `strlen` to get the size of your string.

On the C# side, you can use `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` to convert from a string to a byte array, and `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` to convert from a byte array to a string.

Comment: I added my codes. I dont know how can I do it because if I try to read string from array in C++ for example "İ" letter has 2 bytes like c3 04, but english letters for example "V" is 56 so IDK how to read them.